# If $-m\leq\frac{x}{n}+[\frac{x}{n}]\leq m$ what is the range of $x$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

> If $-m\leq\frac{x}{n}+[\frac{x}{n}]\leq m$ find the range of $x$($x \in \Bbb R,m\in \Bbb Z^+,n\in \Bbb Z$).

Suppose that $k\leq \frac{x}{n}\lt k+1,(k\in \Bbb Z)$ , now :
$$2k\leq\frac{x}{n} + \Big[\frac{x}{n}\Big]\lt2k+1 $$
But how can we relate $k$ and $m$??

Answer (score 2):

Say $y=x/n$. Since $y=[y]+r$ where $0\leq r<1$ we get:

$$-m\leq 2[y]+r \leq m \Longrightarrow {-m-1\over 2}<[y] \leq {m\over 2}$$

So $[y]$ is max $[{m\over 2}]$ and minimal $[{-m-1\over 2}]$.

Since $${x\over n}-1<[{x\over n}]\leq [{m\over 2}]\Longrightarrow x< n\Big([{m\over 2}]+1\Big)$$
and 
since $$\Big[{-m-1\over 2}\Big]\leq [{x\over n}]\leq {x\over n}\Longrightarrow  n\Big[{-m-1\over 2}\Big]<x$$

Comment: What happened to $r$ in line 2??

Comment: I use $0\leq r<1$  to get estimate.

Comment: So it's not EXACT??

Comment: Did you try with concrete values?

Comment: No. I'm curious is there an EXACT method to find range of $x$,not using estimates?

Comment: Thank you any way(+1)